# nodejs http request returns `undefined`

Tags: node.js

While trying to debug the following get request, I notice that it returns `undefined` and then runs the code for the `response`.

`configs` is a json object with all the parameters defined. I am also, for some reason, getting a response form the php server saying that grant-type is invalid or can't be found, although when debugging it is passing the correct parameter from the configs file.

How can I correct my code?

```
var http = require("http");
var querystring = require("querystring");
var _ = require("underscore");

apiCaller = {};

apiCaller.token = null;

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){});

server.listen(8080);

apiCaller._get = function (context, config, fn) {

    // request to obtain our oauth token
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        hostname: config.host,
        client_id: config.clientId,
        client_secret: config.clientSecret,
        grant_type: config.grant_type,
        path: "/my/path/to/token",
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Accept': "application/json"
        }
    };

    var callback = function(response) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        // error response
        response.on("error", function (error) {
            if ( !context ) {
                console.error("Something went wrong with the api response.");
                return;
            }
            context.done(new Error("Something went wrong with the api response."));
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {

            apiCaller.token = JSON.parse(str).access_token;
            // we want to stop the request if token is not correct
            if ( !apiCaller.token || apiCaller.token === undefined || apiCaller.token === null ) {
                if ( !context ) {
                    console.error("Something went wrong with the token. Wrong token! Token: %s", apiCaller.token);
                    return;
                }
                console.error("Token: %s", apiCaller.token);
                context.done(new Error("Something went wrong with the token. Wrong token!"));
            }

        });
    };

    var request = http.request(options, callback);

    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request:');
    });
    request.end();
};
```

Comment: Isn't grant_type supposed to be part of path as a query string? I haven't notice in node docs such an option for request.

Comment: @Molda I'm not sure. What about the client_id and client_secret then?

Comment: neither of those is a option to http.request. you can check it https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: Try to change your path to "/my/path/to/token?grant_type=type&client.... etc.

Comment: Still getting the same response unfortunately.

Comment: Isn't the php server expect the values in body in POST request. How are you trying to get those values? $_POST  $_GET $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?

Comment: Got it returning a 200 response. The order of the querystring was tripping it up. However still have something returning undefined when I call my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an asynchronous function. Asynchronous functions (which are kind of the bread-and-butter of Node.js) typically return nothing. Instead, what you might think of as the return value is passed to the callback function. That's what's happening here.

Comment: Could you help me fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As Trott says, It's asynchronous, it's possible that request.end() is executing before callback function has finished....